# Sip call not properly ended using sipstack

Tags: android, sip

I used the Android built-in sip library to write an app that makes calls via my server. The calls are being made correctly, but most of the time, the calls aren't ended correctly.

This is my code to end the call:

```
public void stopCalling(){
    try {
        call.endCall();
        call.close();
    } catch (SipException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But it does not Ended properly. Is there any other way to ended the sip call.